# Bash wget with variables and wildcard

Tags: linux, bash, wildcards, variable, wget

I've got a file despicting variables:

> IP_1="xx.xx.xx.xx" ID_1="yyyyy"
>
> IP_2="xx.xx.xx.xx" ID_2="yyyyy"
>
> ...
>
> IP_6="xx.xx.xx.xx" ID_6="yyyyy"

I want to execute a wget command with the variables including a wildcard.

> wget --timeout=5 --wait=2 --tries=3 http://"$IP_* "/getcsv/Log_"$EQ_ *".csv
>
> --output-document=/home/administrator/Logs/"$ID_* "/Log_"$EQ_* "*$(date +%F*%T).csv -d -v

After execution of the command it seems like the machine doesn't recognize the variable and gives back /home/administrator/Logs/* /Log_* _2018-03-21_12:03:53.csv for example.

How is it possible for me that the script first uses IP_1 + ID_1, than IP_2 + ID_2, ... from the variable file ?

I tried different versions with [], {}, different " " and as an array. Unfortunately i've got nothing working

thanks

best regards

Comment: What is `EQ_*`? Is it another numbered variable?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this

```
for i in {1..6}; do
    ip_var="IP_$i"
    id_var="ID_$i"
    wget ... "http://${!ip_var}/..." -O "/home/administrator/Logs/${!id_var}/..."
done
```

This uses "variable indirection" as described in the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

However numbered variables are clumsy. Use arrays instead:

```
ip=( "xx.xx.xx.xx" "xx.xx.xx.xx" ... "xx.xx.xx.xx" )
id=( "yyyyy" "yyyyy"... "yyyyy" )

for ((i=0; i < ${#ip[@]}; i++)); do
    wget ... "http://${ip[i]}/..." -O "/home/administrator/Logs/${id[i]}/..."
done
```